# 2016, USA banks with low/no fee for incoming OVERSEAS USD wire transfers?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, fees, wire-transfer, usd-us-dollar

Regarding

- incoming **wire transfers** (i.e., SWIFT transfers)
- from **overseas** (this question has no connection to internal USA transfers of any kind)
- denominated **in USD** (this question has no connection to exchange rates or incoming foreign currencies)
- Ideally, this for **business** accounts, although info re personal accounts is also welcome

Factually, does anyone know of a specific US bank that has no or low fees, for such?

Moreover, after tremendous searching, I could not find an online comparative resource for this - perhaps I'm just missing it.

There are 2-3 *very old* questions similar to this on here, which have poor, confusing, wrong, and out of date answers, or are confused by unrelated issues/answers such as overseas ATM fees or exchange rates, or "local" wire transfers.

It would be great if anyone has *actual experience* of using said bank and receiving transfers.

Comment: VTC. The goal of a canonical answer for a question where the answer  could change at any time is not realistic.

Comment: Hi @mhoran_psprep it's totally normal on Stackoverflow, say, to have "canonical" answers to software questions; those rarely stay current for more than 6 months since software changes constantly.  Anyway I deleted the word, thanks, good point.  Do you have an answer to the question?  the duplicate similar questions are complete junk.

Comment: What is considered "low fees"? A quick search for "banks with no fees for SWIFT" (without the quotes) yielded quite a few sites, such as this one: https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/wire-transfers-what-banks-charge/

Comment: @BobbyScon thanks ... $25 or more is common for incoming overseas wires, $0 would be good.  You know the nerdwallet article is the best of a bad bunch; but it's pretty bad: it includes say "simplebank" which indeed [simply doesn't have](https://www.simple.com/help/articles/deposits/wire-transfers) incoming wires!  doesn't address business accounts, etc.

Comment: Chase takes 15$ flat for incoming wires. Verified in Jun 2016.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I took the first 2 banks from that list that said $0 incoming transfer fees, Ally and Alliant, and both turned out to be true (see answer below). I didn't go through the others, but I think that article is a good starting point. Many of the bigger names waive fees if you're in a certain standing with them. Seeing as this is a Personal Finance forum, I've limited my research to that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Bob - one point; with Ally I fear it might be a trick."we" won't charge a fee but their correspondent bank (ie ... "them") may well do so....  (Much as SimpleBank, another sort of fake "second layer virtual bank" actually doesn't accept wire xfers, see comment above).

Comment: @Aganju - thanks, is that from your actual experience?  Do you bank with chase locally (which region of the country?) or online?  thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow, yes, see http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66751/postbank-germany-transferring-money-to-the-us-what-are-the-best-options where I answered my own q with all details. I opened this account with Chase in FL, in a brick-and-mortar place, but I use it exclusively online.

Answer (score 1):

Ally Bank $0 - from their website (emphasis mine):

> To receive a wire transfer from a non-U.S. bank:
>
> Incoming wire transfers from a non-US bank are processed by our
> designated receiving bank, JP Morgan Chase Bank, N.A.
>
> You'll need to provide the following information to the person or
> business sending the wire transfer to you: Receiving Bank: JP Morgan
> Chase Bank, N.A. ABA/Routing Number: 021000021 Address: 1 Chase
> Manhattan PLZ, New York, NY 10005 SWIFT Code or Bank Identification
> Code: CHASUS33 Beneficiary Account Number: 802904391 Beneficiary Name:
> List 'Ally Bank' since the wire is being processed by JP Morgan Chase
> Bank, N.A. Further Credit: Your Ally Bank Account Number and your name
> as it appears on your Ally Bank account.
>
> **Note: We won't charge you to receive a wire transfer into your Ally
> account.**

https://www.ally.com/help/search.html?term=SWIFT&console=false&context=Help&domain=www.ally.com&section=Help+%26+FAQs

Alliant Credit Union $0 - from their website (emphasis mine):

> Direct international wire transfers
>
> International wire transfers are
> handled through our correspondent bank for processing. International
> wires can take up to 10 business days to be credited to the receiving
> institution.
>
> Funds should be wired to: Northern Trust ABA# 071000152 "Note: US
> Banks do not use SWIFT codes. This ABA # is used in place of SWIFT
> codes for US Banks." 50 South La Salle Street, Chicago, IL 60603
>
> For further credit: Alliant Credit Union Account Number 35101804 11545
> W. Touhy Avenue, Chicago, IL 60666
>
> For final credit: Member’s name and complete address (No P.O. Box)
> Member’s 14-digit account number Destination of funds (checking,
> savings or loan number)
>
> Incoming wire transfers: Wire transfers received Monday - Friday,
> 7:00am - 3:00pm, CT, will be credited to your account the same day.
> Wire transfers received after 3:00pm, CT, Monday - Friday and on the
> weekend will be credited the next business day.
>
> Fees:
> **We do not charge a fee to receive incoming wire funds.** However, the financial institution wiring the funds may charge for this
> service.

http://www.alliantcreditunion.org/help/receiving-a-wire-transfer-to-your-alliant-account